# How to compare two cell in two consequence rows in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql schema as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE Test.Countries 
(id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12;

CREATE TABLE Test.Hotels (id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
country_ids tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL, 
name varchar(255) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=101; 

CREATE TABLE Test.Reservations 
(id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
hotel_ids int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
start_date date NOT NULL, 
nights tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1538;
```

I need to write a query to list all available countries with the number of nights revered based on that country. For example:

```
country              nigths
.................................
 UK                  80
 Argentina           71
 Brazil              71
 Italy               67
```

Table should be ordered based on desc and nights. However, those countries which have the same nights should be ordered based on alphabetic order for countries.

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT  C.name As countries, SUM(R.nights) AS nights FROM Test.Reservations AS R
JOIN Test.Hotels AS H ON R.hotel_ids = H.id
JOIN Test.Countries AS C ON C.id = H.country_ids
GROUP BY C.name
ORDER BY 
      CASE 
          WHEN  nights = Lead(nights) THEN C.name DESC,
          ELSE SUM(R.nights) DESC 
      END;
```

But it raises this error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near '= Lead(nights) THEN C.name DESC, ELSE
> SUM(R.nights) DESC END' at line 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ORDER BY` can take multiple columns, by priority, so that the second column will be used if the values of two rows on the first column are equal. For your case it would be simply something like:

`ORDER BY SUM(R.nights) DESC, C.name`

Comment: Thank you, But it shows Brazil first and then Argentina! Does this say if column `nights` are equal check column `country` in alphabetical order?

Comment: It solved like `ORDER BY  SUM(R.nights) DESC, C.name ASC;`

Comment: Yes, it's read from left to right, ordering column by column until the values differ. I just tried to give an idea how to solve it, and indeed had the columns the wrong way around – I updated the answer nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

You Cannot use Desc within the Case in mySql.

Correct:

```sql
SELECT  C.name As countries, SUM(R.nights) AS nights
FROM TEST.Reservations AS R
JOIN TEST.Hotels AS H ON R.hotel_ids = H.id
JOIN TEST.Countries AS C ON C.id = H.country_ids
GROUP BY C.name
ORDER BY CASE
     WHEN  nights = Lead(nights) THEN C.name
     ELSE SUM(R.nights) 
END '
Desc;
```

Comment: Replace TEST with Test